# Private Constructor Implementation

Tags: c++, constructor, private

As I was reading the C++ Primer 4th edition, I was confused by a particular code snippet.  There was a class definition that is as follows:

```
// handle class to manage the Query_base inheritance hiearchy
class Query {
    // these operators need access to the Query_base* constructor
    friend Query operator~(const Query&);
    friend Query operator|(const Query&, const Query&);
    friend Query operator&(const Query&, const Query&);
public:
    Query(const std::string&);    // builds a new WordQuery
    // copy control to manage pointers and use counting 
    Query(const Query &c) : q(c.q), use(c.use) { ++*use; }
    ~Query() { decr_use(); }
    Query &operator=(const Query&);
    // interface functions: will call corresponding Query_base operations
    std::set<TextQuery::line_no>
      eval(const TextQuery &t) const {return q->eval(t); }
    std::ostream &display(std::ostream &os) const 
                            { return q->display(os); } 
private:
    Query(Query_base &query) : q(query),
                               use(new std::size_t(1)) { }
    Query_base *q;
    std::size_t *use;
    void decr_use()
    { if (--*use == 0) { delete q; delete use; }
};
```

My confusion is about the private constructor.  Why is it there?  I assumed it was to prevent the initialization of a Query object with a Query_base object, but then why do they define the constructor?  Someone please clarify this, thanks.

Note: If you want to look at the class in the book, it's on page 614.

Comment: See those `friend` declarations, with an accompanying comment?

Comment: It is probably used in the implementation of one or both public constructors and/or the assignment operator.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Considering the book is 6 years old, I highly doubt it uses C++11 constructor forwarding.

Comment: *facepalm* thank you, reading that comment again made it clear :)